# How can i make a server side by jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, server, server-side

I have a html file which have a simple form and 3buttons. And JavaScript and jQuery file which have functions counting id,node,attributes  in html.

I want to count id,node,attributes by java too and meke a server side with jsp!!
Is this files right to design? 
 Action.java, findAction.java frontcontroller.java, find.jsp

What keywords can I googling about this?

Comment: Start by writing down/articulating what your functional requirements are.  What does this page need to do exactly?  Let that determine what server side support you might need.

Comment: i want to make sure how many pages i need. like this Action.java, findAction.java frontcontroller.java, find.jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a comprehensive question that is generally not well accepted on SO. I will answer your question in a very informal manner to make it more understandable.

- **Clientside** is what the user sees; it usually consists of HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.
- **Serverside** in the context of web applications, an archetypical backend is usually a program deployed on a remote server that takes requests from the client and delivers data that is not appropriate to include in the web application.

You want to build a program with some buttons that execute some logic without storing any permanent data. That means you do not need to set up a database for your needs.

There are various approaches to setting up your serverside with Java. I would suggest learning about servlets and a framework called Spring. These are both technologies used to build the bridge from clientside to serverside. Here you can count nodes and evaluate what the user has entered.

If you are uncertain how to structure your program, you can look up a prevalent architectural pattern called MVC.